# How can I know $\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t}$ is the inverse of exponential function?

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

How can I know $\int_1^x\frac{dt}{t} \forall x>0$ is the inverse of exponential function assuming I've never heared of the natural logarithm.

Comment: How do you define the exponential function?

Comment: What kind of properties should your inverse satisfy?

Comment: Well, All I know about the exponential function is that it's equals to its derivative. All I know is introductory single variable calculus. And today I learned about Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and its applications to introduce these new functions and that using this type of definitions we can sketch them, evaluate them, or do other stuff with them. I was just wondering how one would know this function is the inverse of a function that its derivative is equals to itself.

Comment: @kptlronyttcna: let $\ln(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{t}$. Then $\ln(e^{x}) = \int_{1}^{e^{x}} \frac{dt}{t}$. Now apply the (second) Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and differentiate. What do you get? Now evaluate at $x=0$ to find...

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/904484/1) might prove helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since $f(x)=e^x$ is a solution of the ODE
$$ f' = f $$
and it is an increasing positive function, given that $g(x)$ is the inverse function of $f(x)$ we have:
$$ g(f(x)) = x,$$
hence by differentiating we get:
$$ f'(x)\, g'(f(x)) = 1, $$
or:
$$ g'(f(x)) = \frac{1}{f'(x)} = \frac{1}{f(x)}, $$
$$ g'(t) = \frac{1}{t}. $$
Since $f(0)=1$ implies $g(1)=0$, the last line gives:
$$ g(t) = \int_{1}^{t}\frac{du}{u}$$
as wanted. The domain of $g$ is the range of $f$, hence we must have $t>0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $f(x)=\int_1^x t^{-1}dt$, for $x>0$. Then, by FTC,

$$f'(x)=x^{-1}.$$

Then:
$$\left(f({\rm e}^x)\right)'=f'({\rm e}^x){\rm e}^x={\rm e}^{-x}{\rm e}^x=1.$$

Hence: $f({\rm e}^x)=x+ C.$ As $f(1)=0$, we have $C=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By the way: Looking at the involved areas under the curve $y={1\over t}$ one verifies easily that
$$\int_1^{x\cdot y}{dt\over t}=\int_1^x{dt\over t}+\int_x^{x\cdot y}{dt\over t}=\int_1^x{dt\over t}+\int_1^y{dt\over t}\ .$$
This says that the function
$$\ell(x):=\int_1^x{dt\over t}\qquad(x\geq1)$$
satisfies the functional equation of the logarithm; furthermore $\ell'(1)=1$.